# How to use the Agent Library at Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, controller, device-detection

what's up? I'm the last two days trying to use a library of DeviceIndentify, [Agent](https://github.com/jenssegers/agent). This is a library based on [Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect), but for **LARAVEL**.
I already read the **README.md** and searched about how to use the library correctly, but I don't get it.
I already installed the library as I should, but I'm not sure about **how to use it**. 
At my tests, I found some problems. I created a Controller where I added the following line codes:

```
use Jenssegers\Agent\Facades\Agent;


class AgentController extends Controller
{
    public function DeviceCheck(){
        $device = "desktop/";

        $agent = new Agent();
        if($agent->isMobile() == true){
            $device = "mobile/";
        }
        return $device;
    }
}
```

And I expected to use the `$device` var in the path of the `view()` method on my `RouteController.php`.Something like:

```
// At Controller
...
return view($device . "welcome");
```

This because I divided my views between `views/desktop/` and `views/mobile/`.

Answer (score 0):

It's only worked in mobile devices, you should test/open page on a mobile device to get that `$device` data.

I recommended you to head over to https://github.com/jenssegers/agent#laravel-optional to proper setup.

Comment: No, it shouldn't show an error just because it's not a mobile device. And I already visited the page you sent...

Comment: You did not mention any error on your question. Mention it on question.